# Помогите расставить знаки в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Выход из зоны комфорта, в котором ты отсиживаешься и скрываешься от
> стресса и жизненных проблем, это портал в лучшую жизнь.

Вопрос: правильно ли расставлены знаки? Или в конце вместо запятой должно стоять тире?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо оформить так:

> "Выход из зоны комфорта, в которой ты отсиживаешься и скрываешься от
> стресса и жизненных проблем,— это портал в лучшую жизнь".

---

Запятая нужна для того, чтобы отделить придаточное предложение от главного (в которой ты отсиживаешься и скрываешься — придаточное; выход из зоны комфорта — это портал в лучшую жизнь — главное), а тире можно обосновать следующим образом: если подлежащее и сказуемое стоят в именительном падеже, являются существительными и связываются друг с другом при помощи  нулевой связки (глагол "есть"), то между этими членами предложения должно быть поставлено тире. К тому же у вас здесь имеется частица "это", подсказывающая, что здесь должно стоять тире.

Comment: *Ajgy*, хотела отредактировать и поддержать ответ, но заметила, что Вы при цитировании изменили **в котором** на **в которой**. Это просто неточность? Или же Вы таким образом поправляете автора? Если второй вариант, то такие изменения необходимо оговаривать, объяснять.